# Dynamic programming: Number of ways of partitioning a set of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

While reading an algorithm book, I found the following exercise.

> Given a set of n elements, write an algorithm that finds number of
>   ways of partitioning it.
>   Example: When n = 2, there are 2 ways of partitioning the set(into
>   two sets with one element, or into the original set and the empty set).

And instead of the algorithm, I tried the python code using dynamic programming.

```
def ways(n):
    dp = [0]*(n+1), 
    sum = [0]*(n+1) ## declaring 2 arrays of n+1 size
    dp[0] = 0
    dp[1] = 1
    sum[0] = 0
    sum[1] = 1
    lastcalc = 1     # last calculated var
    for i in range (2,n):
        if lastcalc < i/2 : 
            for j in range (lastcalc, i/2):
                sum[j] = sum[j-1] + dp[j]
        lastcalc = (i/2) # update the lastcalculated variable
        dp[i] = sum[i/2]
    return dp[n]

print(ways(2))
```

But, the code won't work and gave me an error.

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

My question: how can I fix this? Can I say this code applied a dynamic programming?

Comment: Remove the trailing comma in `dp = [0]*(n+1),`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks for that. It works now but ways(2) is giving me 0. From the question, it supposed to be 2.

Comment: Please post a new question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of the declaration of `dp`. This makes it a tuple, not a list, and tuple are not modifiable. Just remove it, it's a typo.